# Numark Mixtrack Pro as a midi controller?

Tags: production

Can I use a Numark Mixtrack Pro as a midi controller in Ableton or other DAW? For example map fader/knob to cutoff synth or other parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep!

As stated on their website (https://www.numark.com/product/mixtrackpro):

> Mixtrack Pro is also a MIDI-over-USB controller

To map to parameters in Ableton, under *Preferences -> Midi Link* make sure the "remote" option is on, then click the midi button in the top right corner, anything highlighted is mappable, just click what you want to map to set it.